# Internet Sharing failing on Mac OS X Lion Server

Tags: macos, network, internet-sharing

Before I upgraded to Lion Server, I was running 10.7.1

I setup Internet Sharing in the preferences

(Share from Ethernet 1 to Ethernet 2).

After the upgrade, sharing doesn't work unless I take the following steps

1. Login
2. Turn off Internet Sharing
3. Turn Internet Sharing back on

So the question is can I have Internet Sharing on and running even if no one is logged in?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can. I don't think you could even before Lion.

Comment: Previous versions of Mac OS X did this with no problems. 10.7 has this issue.

Comment: copy paste from http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1228469 asked Sep 13, 2011, 05:12 PM

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

I'm typing you this answer through an `InternetSharing`
connexion provided by an iMac running MacOS Lion (10.7.3) where no one is connected:

```
me -> MBP    ………Wi-Fi………   iMac   ………Ethernet………   Internet 
      10.6.8               10.7.3
```

I'm using such a connection for professionnal use
since MacOS 10.4 with no one connected (on the Mac running `InternetSharing`). This connection was used by 5 other Mac (10.4, 10.5,
10.6) and might be considered as a nearly professional grade network.

When you login when your `InternetSharing` is faulty, could you type
in a `Terminal` or `xterm` window:

```
ifconfig -a
ps ax | egrep '(bootp|natp)'
```

My first blind guess is that your main Ethernet connection was shut down
under the responsability of your `Energy Saver` tuning.

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1228469 
is my Forum post. You can't get credit for copy/pasting my own post back to me.